# How to execute code based on integer value

Tags: java, android, if-statement, int

I have an int, `int minion1Hp`, which can be a value of 0 -> 20. Depending on the value it is, a certain image resource will be set for an `ImageView`, using `bar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hpa);`. However, my code currently looks like this:

```
    if (minion1Hp == 0) {
        bar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hp);
    }
    if (minion1Hp == 1) {
        bar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hpa);
    }
    if (minion1Hp == 2) {
        bar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hpb);
    }
    if (minion1Hp == 3) {
        bar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hpc);
    }
    if (minion1Hp == 4) {
        bar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hpd);
    }
    if (minion1Hp == 5) {
        bar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hpe);
    }
```

... and so on. Is there a more efficient way of doing this, rather than a long list of `if` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement with a separate `case` for each instance. On a side note, you shouldn't be using just `if` statements up there, your code will run slowly, you should be using `else if` to make it run faster (since your `hp` can never be 1 and 2 at the same time.

Ex for switch statements:

`switch (minion1Hp){
    case 1: 
       bar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hp);
       break;
    case 2:
       bar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hpa);
       break;`

etc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion: initialize a map at startup (say in `onCreate()`). Like this:

```
mDrawables = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
mDrawables.put(0, R.drawable.hp);
mDrawables.put(1, R.drawable.hpa);
...
```

then just do:

```
bar1.setImageResource(mDrawables.get(minion1Hp));
```

Answer (score 0):

An improvement here would be to change each `if` after the first one to an `else if` as `minion1Hp` can't be multiple values at the same time, but you might find it slightly neater to have the whole thing in a `switch-case` block instead.

Comment: switch is meh, it adds an extra break; after each line.